# Skip multiple input fields in Laravel 4

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4, input-field

I have a couple of fields of type `array` which I want to avoid by using `Input::except()`. How do I do it? HTML is given below:

```
<tr>
   <td>
       {{ Form::input('text', 'batch_name[]', null, ['placeholder' =>'Enter batch name']) }}
   </td>
   <td>
       {{ Form::input('date', 'availability_date[]', null) }}
   </td>
   <td>
       <a class="add" title="Add Row" href="#"><img src="{{URL::to('public/assets/images/plus.png')}}" alt=""/></a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Following does not work and gives error:

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

```
Validator::make(Input::except('_token','batch_name[]','availability_date[]'), $rules);
```

Comment: try `Validator::make(Input::except('_token','batch_name','availability_date'), $rules);` - does that work correctly?

Comment: just remove the `batch_name` from the `$rules`, then it won't be validated.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange No it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the issue. I was using following in redirection:

```
return Redirect::to('admin/item/add')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput(Input::except('_token'));
```

By Changing it to following worked:

```
return Redirect::to('admin/item/add')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput(Input::except('_token','batch_name','availability_date'));
```